# how to copy list<object> without reference C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class MatchTeam
   {
       public int StudentID { get; set; }
       public int PositionName { get; set; }
       public int GroupTeamNumber { get; set; }
   }

[Serializable]

   public class MatchTeamModel : ICloneable
   {
       public List<MatchTeam> MatchAllStudentList { get; set; }

       public object Clone()
       {
           using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               if (this.GetType().IsSerializable)
               {
                   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                   formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
                   stream.Position = 0;
                   return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
               }
               return null;
           }
       }
   }
```

Asp.net mvc

```
 MatchTeamModel Firstlist= new MatchTeamModel
            {
                MatchAllStudentList = new List<MatchTeam>()
            };

 MatchTeamModel Secondlist = new MatchTeamModel
            {
                MatchAllStudentList = new List<MatchTeam>()
            };

MatchTeam MT1 = new MatchTeam { StudentID = 1,Positionname = center,groupteamnumber = 1};
MatchTeam MT2 = new MatchTeam { StudentID = 2 ,Positionname = Forward ,groupteamnumber = 1};
MatchTeam MT3 = new MatchTeam { StudentID = 3,Positionname = Guard,groupteamnumber = 1};
MatchTeam MT4 = new MatchTeam { StudentID = 4,Positionname = center,groupteamnumber = 2};
MatchTeam MT5 = new MatchTeam { StudentID = 5,Positionname = Forward,groupteamnumber = 2};
MatchTeam MT6 = new MatchTeam { StudentID = 6,Positionname = Guard,groupteamnumber = 2};

Firstlist.MatchAllStudentList.Add(MT1)
Firstlist.MatchAllStudentList.Add(MT2)
Firstlist.MatchAllStudentList.Add(MT3)
Firstlist.MatchAllStudentList.Add(MT4)
Firstlist.MatchAllStudentList.Add(MT5)
Firstlist.MatchAllStudentList.Add(MT6)



Secondlist = Firstlist;
```

When i swap or change in Firstlist , Secondlist change too. I need to change some data in Firstlist as
swap MT5 and MT2 but don't change in Firstlist and i try to use deepcopy in MatchTeamModel  but it's not work or maybe i use incorrect. someone pls correct me if i wrong

and if i use

```
Secondlist = Firstlist.Clone() as MatchTeamModel;
```

i have this error

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type
> 'Testcloneobject.Models.MatchTeam' in Assembly 'Testcloneobject,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked
> as serializable.

Comment: The error you post in the image (please post as text, not as image), does not match the classes in your example. But still, read the error message again. It really says exactly what is missing from your code.

Comment: A simple LINQ.Select can be used “non generically” to create new objects with the same data. If this serialization is not needed for other reasons, I would likely remove it entirely.

Comment: Perhaps, consider that each MatchTeam has a Clone method (is which is easy to add). How does this change the approach?

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 'Testcloneobject.Models.MatchTeam' in Assembly 'Testcloneobject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable. I have this error @GvS

Comment: You marked `MatchTeamModel` as `[Serializable]`. And you get an error that MatchTeam is not serializable. Since MatchTeam is referenced by the MatchTeamModel, instances will need to be serialized and deserialized as needed.

Comment: @GvS thank you i forget use [Serializable] on  public class MatchTeam. It's easy.